# Apply CAShapeLayer to multiple UIImageViews inside Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer

I'm trying to round the top corners of a `UIImageView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell`. It worked with my first code but the UICollectionViews performance went way down and started lagging. In a attempt to prevent this I tried to create a variable and just generate a CAShapeLayer for the first cell and then apply the same mask to the rest of the cells. Here is my code:

In `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
In if(maskLayer == nil){
        UIBezierPath *maskPath;
        maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.image.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)];
        maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        maskLayer.frame = cell.image.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    }

    cell.image.layer.mask = maskLayer;

...
```

Far above:

```
@implementation MainViewViewController{    
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer;

}
```

But this does not work. The mast is only getting applied to the last cell that comes in to view when scrolling and gets removed from the rest. Could this solution even work and why is this not working?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**
Tried to creata a subclass of `UIImageView` called `RoundedImageView` as suggested by @debugger and now the code looks like this:

RoundedImageView.m:

```
#import "RoundedImageView.h"

@implementation RoundedImageView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    UIBezierPath *maskPath;
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath *maskPath;
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

In my storyboard I have set the UIImageView class to RoundedImagView and in my custom UICollectionViewCell:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet RoundedImageView *image;
```

But I the viewDidLoad or drawRect in RoundedImageView.m is not getting called at all.

Comment: If `RoundedImageView` is a subclass of `UIImageView` then `drawRect:` won't be called. You'll want to instead subclass `UIView`, set `clipsToBounds` to `YES` and add your `UIImageView` as a subview.

Answer (score 1):

for that you will have to create UIImageview extension class name RoundImageview. and add the following code in the ViewDidLoad method into class:

```
self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; 
self.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2; // Setting the corner radius
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Now in the viewcontroller class add the UIImageview extension in the header  and intitialize like below:

```
RoundImageview *roundimageview;
```

and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method use the following method to add the image:

```
rounfimageview.image = yourimagename
```

I think above method will work..just try and test it.

Comment: Hi thanks. But when I create a subclass of UIImageView i can't get the class to get called. I have breakpoints in viewDidLoad and drawRect

Comment: have you mentioned the newly created class and in the view controller and added reference in the view controller?

Comment: I changed the UIImageView class in the storyboard to RoundedImageView and changed the property in my custom UICollectionViewCell

Comment: i am using this method already.may be you are wrong at some point. without code i can't explain you where you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Create CAShapeLayer for cell. When you create a single instance and try to add for all cell, it will add to the last one.

```
cell.image.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Here it will not create new copy when you assign masklayer.

Edit:

How single instance of layer can be sublayer for more than one layer?.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath: do the following

```
if (!cell) {
// create cell
//And create mask layer
cell.image.layer.mask = maskLayer; // - And do this
}
```

Comment: Sorry how is this different from what I am doing?

Comment: @PaperThick did you try creating shapelayer for each cell?

Comment: Yes I did try that. Then I get the rounded corners but the CollectionView is lagging when scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override drawRect:, and you don't want to put code in viewDidLoad, because that's a UIViewController method, and won't be called in a UIImageView subclass. Since the image view is made in the storyboard, you should put your code in the initWithCoder: method of the UIImageView subclass,

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }
    return self;
}
```